# Migrate Content Types and Site Columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, migration, site-column

Is it possible to migrate the **Content types** and associated **Site columns** from Test Environment to Production Environment of SharePoint 2013 Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, through PowerShell. Phil Childs posted the article [Export and import/create site columns in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/export-and-importcreate-site-columns-in.html) back in 2011.

Basically you export your site columns to an XML-file in your test environment, and import the XML to production.

**Export**:

```
$sourceWeb = Get-SPWeb http://portal
$xmlFilePath = "C:\Install\Script-SiteColumns.xml"

#Create Export Files
New-Item $xmlFilePath -type file -force

#Export Site Columns to XML file
Add-Content $xmlFilePath "<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"utf-8`"?>"
Add-Content $xmlFilePath "`n<Fields>"
$sourceWeb.Fields | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Group -eq "Custom Columns") {
        Add-Content $xmlFilePath $_.SchemaXml
    }
}
Add-Content $xmlFilePath "</Fields>"

$sourceWeb.Dispose()
```

**Import**:

> Once you have the XML file, it can be used to import columns into
>   another site collection by using the script below. The first part of
>   the script gets the destination Web URL and exported XML file:

```
$destWeb = Get-SPWeb http://portal/sites/migrationtest
$installPath = "C:\Install"

#Get exported XML file
$fieldsXML = [xml](Get-Content($installPath + "\Script-SiteColumns.xml"))
```

> The final part of the script cycles through each field specified in
>   the XML file, the properties associated with each column type, and
>   then creates the column in the destination site. Whilst I have
>   included the majority of properties associated with each type of site
>   column (e.g., MaxLength, EnforceUniqueValues, Sortable, etc.), there
>   may still be some properties you need to add yourself as I haven’t
>   tested the script with every column type available in SharePoint:

```
$fieldsXML.Fields.Field | ForEach-Object {

    #Configure core properties belonging to all column types
    $fieldXML = '<Field Type="' + $_.Type + '"
    Name="' + $_.Name + '"
    ID="' + $_.ID + '"
    Description="' + $_.Description + '"
    DisplayName="' + $_.DisplayName + '"
    StaticName="' + $_.StaticName + '"
    Group="' + $_.Group + '"
    Hidden="' + $_.Hidden + '"
    Required="' + $_.Required + '"
    Sealed="' + $_.Sealed + '"'

    #Configure optional properties belonging to specific column types – you may need to add some extra properties here if present in your XML file
    if ($_.ShowInDisplayForm) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'ShowInDisplayForm="' + $_.ShowInDisplayForm + '"'}
    if ($_.ShowInEditForm) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'ShowInEditForm="' + $_.ShowInEditForm + '"'}
    if ($_.ShowInListSettings) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'ShowInListSettings="' + $_.ShowInListSettings + '"'}
    if ($_.ShowInNewForm) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'ShowInNewForm="' + $_.ShowInNewForm + '"'}

    if ($_.EnforceUniqueValues) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'EnforceUniqueValues="' + $_.EnforceUniqueValues + '"'}
    if ($_.Indexed) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'Indexed="' + $_.Indexed + '"'}
    if ($_.Format) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'Format="' + $_.Format + '"'}
    if ($_.MaxLength) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'MaxLength="' + $_.MaxLength + '"' }
    if ($_.FillInChoice) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'FillInChoice="' + $_.FillInChoice + '"' }
    if ($_.NumLines) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'NumLines="' + $_.NumLines + '"' }
    if ($_.RichText) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'RichText="' + $_.RichText + '"' }
    if ($_.RichTextMode) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'RichTextMode="' + $_.RichTextMode + '"' }
    if ($_.IsolateStyles) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'IsolateStyles="' + $_.IsolateStyles + '"' }
    if ($_.AppendOnly) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'AppendOnly="' + $_.AppendOnly + '"' }
    if ($_.Sortable) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'Sortable="' + $_.Sortable + '"' }
    if ($_.RestrictedMode) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'RestrictedMode="' + $_.RestrictedMode + '"' }
    if ($_.UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="' + $_.UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary + '"' }
    if ($_.CanToggleHidden) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'CanToggleHidden="' + $_.CanToggleHidden + '"' }
    if ($_.List) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'List="' + $_.List + '"' }
    if ($_.ShowField) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'ShowField="' + $_.ShowField + '"' }
    if ($_.UserSelectionMode) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'UserSelectionMode="' + $_.UserSelectionMode + '"' }
    if ($_.UserSelectionScope) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'UserSelectionScope="' + $_.UserSelectionScope + '"' }
    if ($_.BaseType) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'BaseType="' + $_.BaseType + '"' }
    if ($_.Mult) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'Mult="' + $_.Mult + '"' }
    if ($_.ReadOnly) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'ReadOnly="' + $_.ReadOnly + '"' }
    if ($_.FieldRef) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n" + 'FieldRef="' + $_.FieldRef + '"' }   

    $fieldXML = $fieldXML + ">"

    #Create choices if choice column
    if ($_.Type -eq "Choice") {
        $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n<CHOICES>"
        $_.Choices.Choice | ForEach-Object {
           $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n<CHOICE>" + $_ + "</CHOICE>"
        }
        $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n</CHOICES>"
    }

    #Set Default value, if specified  
    if ($_.Default) { $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "`n<Default>" + $_.Default + "</Default>" }

    #End XML tag specified for this field
    $fieldXML = $fieldXML + "</Field>"

    #Create column on the site
    $destWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXML.Replace("&","&amp;"))
    write-host "Created site column" $_.DisplayName "on" $destWeb.Url

    $destWeb.Dispose()
}
```

## Content Types

For Content Types, this has already an answer in the question [How to copy content type from one site collection to another site collection in Sp 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/118831/6382).