# Migrate a subsite with content types

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, content-migration

I have a large subsite within a Sharepoint 2016 site hierarchy that I would like to export to a different site collection. The problem is that each document set library in the subsite uses a single content type that's been created at the subsite's parent level. E.g. if my site is at http://example/type/site, the content type and columns are set up at the site http://example/type.

I tried using import/export-spweb to copy the site and its content to the new location, but it only moved the child content types as part of the libraries. How can I move the parent site content type and columns and reassociate them with the child content types? And can I preserve any additional columns or column-hiding present in the child content types?

I'm comfortable enough with Powershell to script importing the content type/columns or updating them on the child items, given some idea of how go about it without losing customisations or more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any third-party migration tool like sharegate, Metalogix etc. Using the tool, first migrate structure of the site, then do the data migration. You can install these tools as a trial free version for some days.

While you are doing the copy structure migration, you can even restructure your site in the target environment, everything is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a tough job just by using PowerShell. Basically, you will have to

1. Do the migration for the subsite.
2. Get references to the Content Types at the source site collection. Recreate the content types in the destination site collection and then assign them to the same objects in the subsite.
3. Go through all contents in the subsite and then redo the assignments.

Third-party tools will be an easier solution, but here are some references on how to migrate / export and import content types to another site collection:

[How to copy content type from one site collection to another site collection in Sp 2013.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118831/how-to-copy-content-type-from-one-site-collection-to-another-site-collection-in)

[Export-Import SharePoint Content Type using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/export-import-content-type-using-powershell.html)